# how to load /etc/sysconfig/iptables on server reboot

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

To enable port 7070 on my server I've run

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT`

through SSH and then

`service iptables save`

which saved rules to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file.

However, when I reboot the server, saved rule is not applied. How can I auto-apply this rule when server restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list state of iptables startup:

chkconfig --list iptables

"Standard" configuration looks like this:

iptables        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

This command set up the defaults:

chkconfig --level 2345 iptables on

If it did not help that there is something wrong with Your OS.

One more thing to try. Please input this command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT
```

(-A is replaced with -I - this will add this rule to the begining of the input chain)
Save iptables state one more time and please test if that helped.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant? What chkconfig --level 2345 iptables on is supposed to do ? because before and after I run this command chkconfig --list iptables still returns iptables        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

Comment: chkconfig - updates and queries runlevel information for system services - simply speaking chkconfig is used for setting which service should be start automaticaly (at system startup). You can also use "ntsysv" command (if there is no such command installed - yum install ntsysv).

Comment: chkconfig --list - list all services and their state (start/stop levels).
chkconfig --level 2345 iptables on - tells that iptables script (from /etc/init.d/iptables) should be started at startup levels 2,3,4 and 5. /etc/init.d/iptables read it's config from file /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

Comment: well but my issue is it doesnt load /etc/sysconfig/iptables on startup so I run your command and it's still not loading config

Comment: see my edits in the above answer. And after restart please attach "iptables -L -n" output in your question